# How do i send push notifications on AWS to flutter apps

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, api, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

Like the Title suggests, how do i send push notifications from AWS to flutter apps? im currently using AWS Amplify for auth calls and REST calls in API gateway. If it is not possible, is there an alternative?

Comment: Upvote for this interesting question !